# setting a sort order column quickly

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-order-by, query-optimization

Suppose I have a SQLite table People with columns `recordId TEXT, name TEXT, job TEXT, sortOrder NUM`.

I want to set the `sortOrder` column for all rows in the table based on sorting the table by name and then job.

I'm currently doing this by:

(1) `SELECT recordId from People order by name, job`

(1b) In the `sqlite3_step()` loop for that SELECT command, save the `recordId` values into a `vector<string> orderedRecordIds`. When we are done with this loop, `orderedRecordIds` has the `recordId` values in the desired order.

(2) In a loop, do a `sqlite3_exec()` for each `recordId` of the form

```
UPDATE People SET sortOrder = <i> WHERE recordId = '<orderedRecordIds[i]>'
```

That all works, but it's too slow.

For a database with 200k records, it takes about 1 second to do step (1), and 12 seconds to do step (2).

I'm not worried about the 1 second to do step (1).

But I'm trying to figure out how to make step (2) faster.

I do have an index on the `recordId` column, which I would think would help with finding each row to set the `sortOrder` value in step (2).

If I use `rowid` instead of `recordId`, it brings step (2) down to 10 seconds.

I was thinking it was all the separate calls to `sqlite3_exec()` that were slowing things down. So I tried doing it all in a single exec statement by building a huge `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE People SET sortOrder = CASE
    WHEN recordId='abc' THEN 0
    WHEN recordId='def' THEN 1
    /* <and so on for 200k rows> */
END
```

but that was *extremely* slow.

I feel like there should be a very fast way to do step (2). By comparison, when I use CREATE INDEX to create an index a column of this large table, it does it in like 20ms. I have this list of ordered record IDs, and just want to say "set the values of a numeric column according to that order."

Perhaps it's faster to create a temporary table with `recordId` and `sortOrder` columns, and then do the update based on a join with that table?

Or perhaps there is a way to do this all in a single step/loop instead of 2?

(By the way, I realize that as the problem is presented I could avoid the need for a `sortOrder` column by just creating an index on the name and job fields. But in my actual application some of the fields I'm sorting by are computed values, in some cases based on values from related tables. This is why I want to have a `sortOrder` column in the first place. Perhaps there is a way I can index based on related values in other tables. But for now please consider my question as stated.)

Comment: "... in my actual application some of the fields I'm sorting by are computed values ..." -- You should elaborate on this [edit] the question and include a [example].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use window functions, which are available in SQLite starting version 3.25 ?

If I followed you correctly, the following query gives you the result that you want:

```
select p.*, row_number() over(order by name, job) rn from people p;
```

You could just use this query to create a view rather than storing the value... When it comes to updating the table, it is a bit more complicated, because sqlite does not support joins in update statements. You could first materialize a temporary table that contains the sort orders, then use it to update your table, like:

```
create temp table people_tmp as
select recordId, row_number() over(order by name, job) rn from people;

update people
set sortOrder = (
    select rn from people_tmp pt where pt.recordId = people.recordId
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on window functions and using a temp table. When I ran your `set sortOrder = ...` command, it was extremely slow (I let it run for 10 minutes before killing it). But when I added an index to the temp table on recordId, that brought the `set sortOrder = ...` runtime down to about 4 seconds. So, I'd still like to find a way to set that column faster (after all, it takes less than a second to create an index on a field of my 200k row table, so you'd think there would be a way to set a column to a list of known values in that time or better). But I'll mark the answer accepted.